# Which Official ISO do I Download?

Tags: 64-bit, cpu, operating-systems, x86

I wanted to do a clean install of my Win7 after I get my HDD so I decided to download the Official ISO [from here](http://www.mydigitallife.info/download-windows-7-iso-official-32-bit-and-64-bit-direct-download-links/).I got this link from HP's website. I have the product key with me but  not  the  discs as the OS was pre-installed.
My laptop is HP DV4-2126TX with First Generation i3 processor.

does x86 = 32Bit Processor and x64 = 64bit Processor? and **i3** is how many bits?

Do I install Win7 Home Premium 32bit or 64 bit?

I know when you buy a laptop the cost includes that of the OS so I guess its no piracy moving from a 32bit OS to a 64bit OS as the cost includes both.
Please answer with reference to the site as to which one do I download.

Comment: From what I can tell, all Core i3 processors are `x86-64`. Simply put, they are 64-bit. [`x86`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86) is "32-bit", while [`x86-64`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86-64) is "64-bit".

Comment: and they get their name because they are descendants of the original Intel 80X86 processors?

Comment: `x86` refers to the instruction set originally introduced with the 8086 (originally 16-bit). `x86-64` is an extension of the x86 instruction set, but 64-bit, also known as `AMD64` and `Intel 64` and backwards compatible with `x86` - that's why it's an extension, instead of being totally different. `x86` is also a common name for the 32-bit implementation of that instruction set (also known as `IA-32`, `x86-32`, etc.). There are many other instruction sets and processor architectures, one of them is Itanium by HP and Intel, also known as `IA-64`, a 64-bit architecture incompatible with `x86`.

Comment: what I get from your first few sentences: 32bit processor will not support 64bit OS, only 32bit but 64bit processor will support both

Comment: Generally, though, with consumer CPUs you'll see `x86` (meaning 32-bit, backwards compatible with 16-bit) and `x86-64` (meaning 64-bit, backwards compatible with 32-bit and 16-bit). An OS will run as long as the processor is (backwards) compatible with it. Fun fact: Windows (XP/Vista/7) refers to `x86-64` as `AMD64` internally, since that was the original name.

Comment: so are 32bit processors even manufactured anymore?

Comment: I can't remember seeing any within the past few years.  Intel, starting from the `Core2` family on have all been 64-bit processors.  No, I stand corrected.  The `Intel Atom` series of CPUs are 32-bit only.  They're standard in netbooks and really low cost PCs.

Comment: @UtahJarhead The Atom processors are all `x86-64` with the exception of the first two netbook ones (Diamondville), it seems: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Intel_Atom_microprocessors#.22Diamondville.22_.2845_nm.29_3 I'm not sure about AMD.

Comment: Didn't know the later ones are x64 capable.  Good to know!  My netbook was one of the originals, so that explains it's relegation to 32-bit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Intel Core i3 is in fact a 64bit CPU, I'd go with the 64bit ISO.

But I doubt that this link was from HP.

Comment: A user asked  the same question as I did in the forum a bout getting Win7 ISO. Someone posted that link as an answer and  he had an 'Expert' badge

Comment: I see.

The x64 is actually 64bit x86, so that's it.

Comment: `The x64 is actually 64but x86, so that's it` what do you mean?

Comment: I edited, it was an unfortunate typo, you need the x64 ISO.

Comment: @FasihKhatib You *could* use the 32-bit ISO as long as you have under 4 GB of RAM (and no intention of upgrading), which will also save some disk space (64-bit is larger). The 64-bit version of Windows also does not support 16-bit programs, and many programs will use more RAM when running. Also, 32-bit Windows tends to have slightly better driver support, though more recently 64-bit drivers have become easy enough to find. On the other hand, for intensive mathematical/scientific calculations and simulations, 64-bit Windows may be faster.

Comment: @FasihKhatib - You need to use a Windows 7 OEM ISO the ISO your asking about is a Retail ISO and won't work with your OEM license of Windows 7.

Comment: "But I doubt that this link was from HP." Yes it is, its posted in the HP forums many many times.